# How to fix loose valve?

Tags: tire

I was pumping my tires when a valve pushed in, deflating the tire in the process. It pushes in and out, but won't stay in place. I'm not really into biking so I'm completely clueless

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  A photo or video would help us understand what the problem is.  As it is we don't even know what kind of valve your tyre has.

Comment: If pushing the valve stem in caused the tire to deflate then it is probably a tubeless tire.  You may want to install tubes to make the whole mess less confusing.

Answer (score 2):

I presume that the tire is *very* flat at this point. You'll have to hold the valve in position with one hand while you get air in it, holding the chuck with the other hand. Once it reaches a minimum internal pressure, air pressure alone will hold the valve firmly against the rim and you'll be able to finish pressuring the tire without holding the valve.

One of the advantages of a Presta valve over a Schrader is that the Presta is threaded and you install a nut on those threads that holds the valve in place for that initial fill.

This is a Schrader valve (note that you'll only see the black part on the right side, the left side shows the internals of the valve without its rubber coating):

[image: Image of a Schrader valve and its internals]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve)</sup>

This is a Presta valve:

[image: Image of a Presta valve]
<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presta_valve)</sup>